Does $E[E[X|X\le Y]]=E[X]$?
This is a question I came up with while doing some related calculations.
Let $X$ be a random variable defined on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$. To make everything as nicely behaved as possible, let $X$ be supported on $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$, and assume that $X$ has a density $f$ that is continuous and strictly positive on $[a, b]$. Denote the cdf of $X$ by $F$. Define $\phi: [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ by
$$
\phi(t) =
\begin{cases}
E[X|X\le t]=\frac{1}{F(t)} \int_a^t x f(x) dx, & t \in (a,b],\\
a, & t=a.
\end{cases}
$$
Now let $Y$ be another random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$, independent of $X$. Assume that $Y$ is also supported on $[a,b]$ and that $Y$ has a density $g$ that is strictly positive and continuous on $[a,b]$. Denote the cdf of $Y$ by $G$.
Question: Is it true that
$$\tag{1}
E[\phi(Y)] = E[X]?
$$
Some remarks:

Note that we can write $(1)$ in the suggestive form $E[E[X|X\le Y]] = E[X]$. But I'm not sure whether this is a valid application of the law of iterated expectations.

I've tried to verify $(1)$ directly but so far I haven't succeeded. Here is what I have so far:
\begin{align}
E[\phi(Y)]
&= \int_a^b \frac{1}{F(y)} \int_a^y x f(x)\, dx\, g(y) dy\\
&= \int_a^b \frac{1}{F(y)} \left([xF(x)]_a^y-\int_a^y F(x)\, dx\,\right) g(y) dy\\
&= \int_a^b  \left(y-\int_a^y F(x)\, dx\,\right) g(y) dy,
\end{align}
where the first equality follows from the definition, the second from integration by parts and the third because $F(a)=0$. But I don't know how to continue from here (or if $(1)$ even holds).


Thank you!

Firstly
If it exists, then $\mathsf E(X\mid X<Y)$ is a constant.   The expectation of a constant is itself.
$\mathsf E(X\mid X<Y)$ does not always equal $\mathsf E(X)$.
As a counter example, consider $X,Y\overset{\rm iid}\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$.
Then $\mathsf E(X)=1/2$ but $\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid X<Y))=1/3$.

However
I suspect you are looking for $\phi(Y)= \mathsf E(X\mid X<t)\vert_{t:=Y}$, a different beast altogether.
But still...
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid X<t)\vert_{t:=Y}) &= \int_a^b \mathsf E(X\mid X<y)\, g(y)\,\mathrm d y\\&=\int_a^b\dfrac{\int_a^y x f(x)\,\mathrm d x}{\int_a^y f(x)\,\mathrm d x}\, g(y)\,\mathrm d y\end{align}$$
And again with our counterexample
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\phi(Y)) &= \int_0^1\dfrac{y^2/2}{y}\mathrm d y\\&= 1/4\\&\neq \mathsf E(X)\end{align}$$

Thanks, both parts of your answer are really helpful. To elaborate a bit in case I come back to this later (correct me if I'm wrong):
In the first part of your answer, $E[X|X\le Y] = E[X|A]$ where $A$ is the event ${X\le Y}$. Then $E[X|A]$ is simply the average of $X$ over some set, so this is of course constant.
In the second part of your answer it becomes clear that $E[X|A] = E[X|X\le Y]$ is not the same as $\phi(Y)$, so one has to be careful with the notation there.
One question: How do you get $E[E[X|X<Y]]=1/3$ in the first part of your answer?

@Epiousios When $X,Y\overset{\rm iid}\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$ then $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X\mid X<Y) &= \int_0^1\int_0^y x,\mathrm d x,\mathrm d y\div \mathsf P(X<Y)\[1ex]&=\int_0^1 y^2/2,\mathrm d y\div (1/2)\[1ex]&= 1/3\end{align}$$

No, this is not true. Imagine that $Y$ is constant* and equal to $0$, and that $X$ is standard normal (or just anything with a symmetric PDF -- in particular, finite support as in your simplifying assumption is fine). Then $\mathbb{E}(X | X < Y)$ is also constant, and so its expectation is just itself, which is negative.
(*This doesn't meet your simplifying criteria, which turn out to make things harder, but we could replace the constant $Y$ with a function with most of its mass near $0$ and the result would stay the same.)
